# Getting an error while taking input from an embedded python code

Tags: python, linux, bash, python-2.6

I have a bash script that invokes python2.6 for reading input , but i'm encountering an error.
Below is the script. I'm running the bash script from terminal

```
a=1
b=2
python2.6 <<"EOF"
a=int(input('Enter num 1'))
b=int(input('Enter num 2'))
ptint('a=%d ' % a)
print('b=%d ' % b)
EOF

c=$((a + b))
echo "$c"



Enter num 1Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
3
```

Comment: Line 6 `ptint` should be `print`!

Comment: sorry for typo , still getting the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Enter num 1Traceback (most recent call last):
```

You pass your script in through `stdin` and you also want your user input on `stdin`. `input` raised it since it got nothing. In any case, you could use a different construct (like process substitution) to "embed" that python code. E.g.:

```
...
python2 <(cat <<"EOF"
a=int(input('Enter num 1'))
b=int(input('Enter num 2'))
print('a=%d ' % a)
print('b=%d ' % b)
EOF
)
...
```

That won't fail, but is likely not doing what I assume is you wanted it to do. Take the prints and use them to redefine the values of bash variables.

For that you would have to wrap the whole python call in another pair if `$(...)` for command substitution. However, that would also gobble your input prompts (making them invisible and confusing the heck out of shell). I do not think `input` let's you use `stderr` for prompts to get around that. (It also has another problem of performing `eval` on the input, which could expose you to whole array of other problems and is probably not a function you want to use in this case).

I am not entirely sure where this script was heading, but I hope this gives you something to go on with.

Comment: any alternate way to achieve this ?

Comment: I've edited the answer with more detail and few corrections, but to that specific question. Not sure where this is heading... and why not use shell to read in the values?